# XML animation accelerates and decelerates at beginning and end, despite using linear_interpolator

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I need my two animations to repeat continuously, with no pause in between. However, every time, it accelerates at the beginning of the animation, and decelerates towards the end.

My XMLs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="10000"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:toYDelta="-1%p" />

</set>



 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="10000"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:toYDelta="99%p"
        android:startOffset="0" />

</set>
```

Any help appreciated.

Note: The Deltas were originally at 100 instead of 99, and 0 instead of 1, but it didn't help the case.

Comment: Trying putting the android:interpolator tag up in the main set tag. <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

Comment: Cool :) I'll post as answer for the future people to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Put the android:interpolator tag up in the main set tag.

< set xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

So if you look the source code the AnimationSet(context,  resource file) constructor, defaultly sets the shared interpolator to true ie. Pass true if all of the animations in this set should use the interpolator associated with this AnimationSet. Pass false if each animation should use its own interpolator. Hence you need to put the interpolator on the set and not the animation piece itself.